# How to find overlaps in text array in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to add constraint to some column and for that I used string_to_array function, then I need to check some overlaps with the help of && operator, but I get an error: data type text[] has no default operator class for access method "gist". How I can fix it? Perhaps I need to add some extension? Or Posgress doesn't support such cases

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , unfortunately, GIN doesn't support exclusion constraints, but I need to create it

Comment: Can you share your table definition?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I can't, but I can explain, I have a column for example with name col, and in this column stores folowing text: "a,b,c" "x,e" "d,j". And I need to make exclude constraint to avoid insert data which already exists, so I can't add "a,n" because "a" already exists

Comment: @AndriiStasiuk ah. An exclusion constraint requires an index, which is not available for `text[]`. A normal filter would wrk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table probably looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE texts (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   vals text[] NOT NULL
);
```

If you had properly normalized the table, the solution would be easy:

```
CREATE TABLE texts (
   id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE texts_vals (
   id bigint REFERENCES texts NOT NULL,
   val text PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Uniqueness is guaranteed automatically!

With the text array, it cannot be done with a simple constraint.

You could create a trigger that checks the condition, but [triggers are always subject to race conditions](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/) by concurrent data modifications unless you use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.